# Converting from SP initiated SSO to IdP initiated SSO

Tags: .net, single-sign-on, integration, saml-2.0

I am a complete novice at SSO, so please let me know if my question doesn't make sense. Our internal system currently supports SP-initiated SSO. We have completed one successful integration with a third-party application, but our latest vendor only supports IdP-initiated SSO. What are my options at this point? Is the integration still possible? I don't even know where to start, so any help pointing me in the right direction would be highly appreciated.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Kellen it should just work.

You just need to figure out the "magic link" - the URL that takes you to the IDP Initiated screen e.g. in Azure AD, the link takes you to the authentication screen and then through to the application.

Answer (score 0):

IdP-initiated means they are just going to invoke a URL at the IdP that will automatically generate the SAMLResponse and return the user to your application with that response. So long as your SAML stack can accept unsolicited responses (very likely) you should be fine.

If you were using, say Shibboleth, it would be guaranteed to work.

What does your SAML implementation look like? We'd need to know how you implemented SAML in order to tell you with 100% certainty, but it's incredibly likely you can just do the integration the same way, and it'll work.

In my experience, IdP-initiated SSO is something that seems to confuse everybody but there's really no mystery to it. Also... I find it unlikely that your client doesn't support SP-initiated SSO, they just don't know their stack well enough to give you the correct endpoints. There's a whole lot of "stuck inside the box" thinking in the SAML world.

Comment: Thank you Kellen. We decided to use their API for integration this time, but your answer helped point me in the right direction should we need to use SAML next time.